# How to Prove that $[(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)]^7$>$7^7a^4b^4c^4$

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers, then prove that $[(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)]^7$>$7^7a^4b^4c^4$. I am stuck on this question and do not know how to proceed. Any hint or clue how I might tackle this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $abc=x^{21}$.

Hence, by Holder $$\sum_{cyc}(1+a)\geq\left(1+\sqrt[3]{abc}\right)^3=(1+x^7)^3.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$1+x^7>\sqrt[3]7x^4,$$
which  follows from AM-GM:
$$1+x^7=3\cdot\frac{1}{3}+4\cdot\frac{x^7}{4}\geq7\sqrt[7]{\frac{x^{28}}{3^3\cdot4^4}}>\sqrt[3]7x^4.$$
Done!

Answer (score 2):

We have to prove  $$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)>7 (abc)^{\frac {4}{7}} $$ $$\Rightarrow 1+\sum a +\sum ab + abc >7 (abc)^{\frac {4}{7}} $$ We know by AM-GM inequality $$\sum a \geq 3 (abc)^{\frac {1}{3}} \text {    and    } \sum ab \geq 3 (abc)^{\frac {2}{3}} $$ Hence, $$\text {LHS } \geq 1+ 3 (abc)^{\frac {1}{3}} +3 (abc)^{\frac {2}{3}} + abc = 1+ (abc)^{\frac {1}{3}} + (abc)^{\frac {1}{3}} + (abc)^{\frac {1}{3}} + (abc)^{\frac {2}{3}} + (abc)^{\frac {2}{3}} + (abc)^{\frac {2}{3}} + abc \geq 7\sqrt [7]{(abc)^2 (abc)(abc)} =7 (abc)^{\frac {4}{7}} $$ Hope it helps.